# Inline Images not displaying under org-mode

Tags: org-mode, inline-image

I was trying to use org-mode to organize my notes as usual and produce some reports, but can't get images to display inline. This used to work in the past, but doesn't seem to work anymore, any tips what I'm doing wrong?

I have a png in the current *.org document folder called audit.png which I linked by adding a link `[[file:audit.png][audit image]]` but it simply doesn't show up.

When I do `C-c C-x C-v` to display the image inline it says there aren't any.

This is my emacs version:
[image]

And these are my variables controlling the image search (with values below):

```
image-file-name-extensions
; => ("png" "jpeg" "jpg" "gif" "tiff" "tif" "xbm" "xpm" "pbm" "pgm" "ppm" "pnm" ...)

image-file-name-regexps
; => nil
```

If I open the link with `C-c C-o` I can see the image within emacs though which confuses me even more.

This would help me a lot in work. Thank you for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

Oh boy, this post had the answer: [Org-mode: No images to display inline](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10114/org-mode-no-images-to-display-inline)

Apparently if you add a description to the image the inline display won't work.

Comment: But according to another answer to the same question (that should really be a comment), `C-u C-c C-x C-v` does inline image links with descriptions.